# In ADF Mobile, how to select multiple images and delete them in the page?

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf-mobile

I have create my image list page like this, using the listView to display the images:

```
image1    image2
image3    image4
image5
```

And now there is a requirement that I need to select the images to delete.
Can I make the listItem selected?
How to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using jDeveloper or Eclipse? Which version of ADF?

Comment: Using the JDeveloper. by the way, I have fixed this.

Comment: Please share the solution :)

Comment: Hi Brian, I have post my solution here. Please have a look. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I did as below:

In the amx file, add an  component into the :

```
<amx:selectBooleanCheckbox id="sbc1" inlineStyle="width:#{(deviceScope.hardware.screen.availableWidth/2)-10}px;"
                                       value="#{row.deleted}"/>
```

Here the value of row.deleted will be set to true, when the user click the selectBooleanCheckbox.

Then in the related ManagedBeans class, we can check if the value of row.deleted is true or not.

Iterate the imageList, If the value of deleted is true, then we remove the related image from the image List. For example:

```
Iterator itr = imageList.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()) {
    ImageFile imageItem = (ImageFile) itr.next();
    if (imageItem.isDeleted()) {
        itr.remove();
    }
}
```

Here the ImageFile is a class to store the image. It contains:

```
private String   imageFile;
private Integer  imageFileId;
private boolean  deleted;
```

and the getter and setter.